# AssetManager and native code

Tags: android-ndk

I have a config.txt file. The file is not compressed during the apk build using the nocompress extension="txt" option. Then I'm openning in my java code asset manager and passing it to the native function. Finally I'm opening a File* using the below code.
The problem is that when calling fgets(line, 32, file) - where line is char * - the content of line is not what is the first line of the file.

```
AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
if(NULL == mgr) return -1;
AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "config.txt", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
if (NULL == asset) {
    return -1;
}
off_t start, length;
int fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(asset, &start, &length);
if (fd < 0)
    return -1;
 FILE * file = fdopen(fd, "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in https://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/source/browse/trunk/jni/aapt/jni/Package.cpp (search for "static const char* kNoCompressExt" ) txt is not in the exclude list and may be compressed!
Actually this should lead to fd beeing smaller than zero.