# Relative Addressing in native part of an Android application

Tags: android, android-ndk, relative-addressing

I have an object creation in my native part of an Android application like this:

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
face_cascade.load( "haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );
```

In pure c++ you place **haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml** in **haarcascades** folder besides your sources. But now I'm really confused where it should be placed ? In jni/haarcascades directory ? Or somewhere else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android application starts with the filesystem root as current directory. Also, when you deploy an Android app, you normally put the files either in `res/raw` directory, or in `assets` directory of your Java project. You can access `assets` directly form native code (see http://www.costrategix.com/blog/reading-files-from-android-assets-folder-using-c-ndk/ and [AssetManager and native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791109/assetmanager-and-native-code)).

Android isolates file access for different apps, so that each can store its private files. Android apps often use the `/sdcard/` for file storage because there is usually much more space there. Also, it's easier for the native code to find the files on the **sdcard**. But be careful: `/sdcard/` may not be present on some devices under some circumstances. Often, Android system will have an *environment variable* `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` which may be used instead; but the official supported way to find this path is through [Java API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

It is impossible to manipulate the *current directory* from Java, but you can use JNI for that.

Anyways, the native code has the same file access permissions as the Java code.

Comment: Thanks man. A question ! Does /sdcard/ change based on device? For example /sdcard/ in Galaxy SIII is /sdcard0/. Should I use /sdcard0/ or /sdcard/ will map to /sdcard0/?

Comment: There exists a [special Java API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to find the true path. Please read the details carefully, they may be important to you (e.g. multiuser scenario).